# jquery ajax Long Polling append error parsererror (SyntaxError: Unexpected token <)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make a ticker like facebook with Jquery Ajax long poll and php.

My script display: error parsererror (SyntaxError: Unexpected token <).

What is the cause of these error in my script please?

My Jquery script:

```
function addmsg(from_id, detail, time){
    $("#updatetime").append(
        "<div class='upbox1'>"+ from_id +" "+ detail +" "+ time +"</div>"
    );
}
function waitForMsg(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "upsidenew2.php",
        async: true,
        cache: false, 
        timeout:50000,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){ 
        if(data) {
        addmsg(data);
        }
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, 
                1000 
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, 
                15000); 
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    waitForMsg(); 
});
```

upsidenew2.php

```
include_once("mysessionone.php");
if($session->logged_in){
global $dbh;
$myid = $session->id;

//Find out follow And followers
$q = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM follow WHERE friend_one='$myid' OR     friend_two='$myid'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
$f_id = $row['friend_one'];
$f2_id = $row['friend_two'];

//convert follow and followers id's
$s1 = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT bdid,username FROM users WHERE `bdid`='".$f_id."' OR `bdid`='".$f2_id."'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($s1)) {
$fbdid = $row["bdid"];
$fusername = $row['username'];

//find out post id's of user's and followers
$g = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT parent_id FROM updateside WHERE `from_id`='".$fusername."' OR `to_id`='".$fbdid."' OR `from_id`='".$session->username."' OR `to_id`='".$session->id."' GROUP BY parent_id DESC") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($g)) {
$parent = $row['parent_id'];
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
$timestamp = date("M j, y; g:i a", time() - 2592000);

//here is user's related post to echo
$u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM updateside WHERE `parent_id`='".$parent."' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."' ORDER BY created DESC") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($u)) {
$data['from_id'] = $row['from_id'];
$data['parent_id'] = $row['parent_id'];
$data['to_id'] = $row['to_id'];
$data['sub'] = $row['sub'];
$data['detail'] = $row['detail'];
$data['img'] = $row['img'];
$data['time'] = $row['created'];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
exit;

}
}
break;
}
} else { echo '<div class="mass1">No Update</div>'; }
} else { echo '<div class="mass1">Login to see</div>'; }            //session close
```

Comment: Can you check your AJAX request's response data through the browser in some way? (Probably the Network inspector) I think the problem may be in the response from your PHP script.

Comment: Network inspector show ok response data

Comment: That isn't what I meant. Does the response data start with `<`?

Comment: no at start < anywhere sir.

Comment: Can you add the response data to the question?

Comment: ok, sir see this page : bdshowbiz.com/loginfinal/longpoll2.php

Comment: Well, of course it's giving an error. `upsidenew2.php` is returning `HTML`, whereas jQuery expects `JSON` response, because of your `dataType: "json"` parameter. Can you show us the source of `upsidenew2.php` ?

Comment: edit: full upsidenew2.php here above

Comment: It seems that it's returning HTML because `the session does not exist`. That is, I'm not logged in.

Comment: session added and edit above also but not change

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to say is that `I` cannot login, to see the response. Whatever browser you are using, press `f12`, go to network tab, reload the page, click on the request to `upsidenew2.php`, copy the response data from there and update it in your question.

Comment: If I have no wrong I updated at above sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67626/discussion-between-abhishek-and-koch).

Answer (score 0):

your problem maybe this:

echo json_encode($data);

I also had this problem and i'm using this:

echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{answer : true}" . ')';

Where callback is just a parameter in your request query. Also try dataType:'jsonp'

Hope this helps.

Comment: Am I replace echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{answer : true}" . ')'; with echo json_encode($data);? dataType:'jsonp' not work.

Comment: What does the console say with this "setup"?

Comment: console have no change also and don't show any error too

Comment: Ok - so make a screenshot of the console with your first version of the code.

Comment: ok, sir see this page with $_GET['callback']:  http://bdshowbiz.com/loginfinal/longpoll.php

Comment: Ok - for me this is not "long polling". You are just requesting the server every 15 seconds. Even if this doesn't solve your problem right now you should try Server Sent Events - super easy to implement and less overhead. Check this simple example here:http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: Thank u sir, I am trying. .